# jquery 'hover mouseover' function jumpy

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, mouseover

This is my code for html and jquery, when hover over the img1 the content_hidden_popout shows up, but still on img1 and moving around its really really jumpy, like it down just stay until mouse over is no longer on img1.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img1").on('hover mouseover', function() {
        //alert('test');
        $(".content_hidden1").show();
        $(".content_hidden2, .content_hidden3, .content_hidden4, .content_hidden5, .content_hidden6, .content_hidden7, .content_hidden8, .content_hidden9, .content_hidden10").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <img class="img1" src="<?php echourl(); ?>/images/slider/1.png" />
    <div class="content_hidden1 content_hidden_popout">
        <h3>Schools</h3>
        <p>text, text, text</p>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 63 ); ?>">
            <img class="learn-more" src="<?php echourl(); ?>/images/learn-more.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) has an option for two event handlers. One for `mouseover` and one for `mouseout`.

But the real reason that it is jumpy is because when you hover over the image, the popover will be shown in front of the the image. This means that you're no longer hovering over the image so the image is hidden, which causes you to be hovering over the image again, etc etc...

To fix this, apply the event handler to the parent element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img1").parent().hover(
        function() {
            $(".content_hidden_popout").hide();
            $(".content_hidden_popout", this).show();
        },
        function() {
            $(".content_hidden_popout").hide();
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use this form of code:

```
$("selector").hover(
   function()
   {
       $(this).show();
   },
   function()
   {
       $(this).hide();
   });
```

This is a special property of `hover()` function which allows use of two `function()`(s) separated by a comma. Its because it is very common to use `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` together, and writing them repeatedly can make the code bigger.

And using `show()` and `hide()` in such way as you used, is preferrably not recommended.